# A design pattern to avoid multiple ifs

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I have a really awfull class with two methods that start or stops some services when that services are available. Something like the following (they are not if-elses, just if):

```
void startServices() { 
if (service1 == true) { 
  start1();
}
if (service2 == true) { 
  start2();
} if (serviceN == true) { 
  startN();
} 
} 


void stopServices() { 
if (service1 == true) { 
  stop1();
}
if (service2 == true) { 
  stop2();
}
if (serviceN == true) { 
  stopN();
}

}
```

Do you recommend me any design patter to make it prettier?

Thanks!

Comment: I won't answer this because existing answers are good, but I would just like to point out that `== true` is somewhat redundant in any `if()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends; my first reaction is to store the services in a hash or array.  Each service implements an interface with start and stop methods. Starting or stopping a service  then requires only a service key or index.

It's still a bit brittle, perhaps, but without known more I'm not sure how to "domainify" ut so it looks more like what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Strategy pattern.

The idea is that you should know what strategy you're going to use when you instantiate your class (or you can change it dynamically latrr). Therefore, you can pass in that strategy upon instantiation (and optionally replace it later).

```
public interface IStartupStrategy
{
    void Start();
}

public interface IStopStrategy
{
    void Stop();
}

public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IStartupStrategy> startupStrategies;
    private readonly IEnumerable<IStopStrategy> stopStrategies;

    public MyClass(IEnumerable<IStartupStrategy> startup, IEnumerable<IStopStrategy> stop)
    {
        this.startupStrategies = startup;
        this.stopStrategies = stop;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        foreach(var strategy in this.startupStrategies)
        {
            strategy.Start();
        }
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        foreach(var strategy in this.stopStrategies)
        {
            strategy.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me the impression that the Strategy pattern was blindly applied to this problem. I don't think the naming makes too much sense; there are multiple start-up strategies? One for each service?

Comment: Indeed. I was attempting to give a clear representation of the pattern, but in doing so I broke up what *should* have been an "IService" into multiple start and stop strategies. Ideally you would use the "IService" interface which would have start and stop methods. Then that service can decide if it wants to implement either the start or stop. The services would be passed in based on what services are available, and the calling class would decide *when* those services should be started or stopped. It's still the strategy pattern, but the strategy would have more than one method.

Comment: I just re-read what I wrote in the prior comment. If the strategy pattern is essentially passing in some algorithm to be executed that the calling class does not supply... would inversion of control as a whole possibly be considered a strategy pattern? Just a thought.

Comment: I think the relationship between the two is: inversion of control is implemented via the Strategy pattern. It could be implemented in many different ways, but Strategy seems to be a straightforward way to do it. One of them is what you want to do (invert control) and the other one is how you do it (using the strategy pattern).

Comment: @Guven, +1 for a pragmatic answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use Objects, where you have a list of Services which you can iterate through turning them off with an inherited method stop().

```
public interface Service {
  void start();
  void stop();
}

public class TestService implements Service {
  @Override
  void start() {
  }

  @Override
  void stop() {
  }
}
```

Each service can also store its state so as to only turn them off if they are on.

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements are less confusing. If used together with enums code becomes very readable.